# How to go to catch block without throwing exception

Tags: java

I have a java class which is throwing `IOException`.I have some code in Catch block which i need to debug. I don't know in which case my java class is throwing exception. So I need to go to catch block explicitly without throwing. Can it be possible.

Please help me out.

Comment: Post the code if possible. As you know the Exception is IOException, look at the API your code is invoking in try which throw this kind of exception. Also, every exception includes stack-trace, which tell you the exact place the exception was thrown from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code in a catch block is not executed if no matching exception is thrown in the `try` block.

The only way to execute it is to cause the `IOException` to be thrown.

You can just put an explicit `throw new IOException();` as the last line in the `try` block.

Alternatively, you might be able to pull the contents of the `catch` block into a separate method, which you can then invoke explicitly.

Comment: What if last line is a return statement?

Comment: Then the catch block isn't going to be executed, unless a method call in the return expression throws an exception of the same type.

Comment: Is there a way to throw the exception explicitly in that case?

Comment: Yes, as in the answer `throw new IOException()`. Note that both a return statement and a throws statement terminate normal execution, so you can't have both: only one will be executed, the other is unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

Control wont goto catch block if exception is not thrown. Put the code in `finally` block which you want to execute irrespective of whether exception thrown or not.

Sample:

```
try {

} catch() {

} finally {
//Put code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

but if the exception is thrown you will be directed towards finally block or you can post sample code so one might help you